# TypeError: null is not an object while using react-native-live-audio-stream,

Tags: react-native

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNLiveAudioStream.init')]

Comment: You most likely need to include your code

Comment: Please add more details